# Java library supporting XPointer with the xpointer() scheme?

Tags: java, xpointer

Is there any java library supporting XPointer with the xpointer() scheme?

Xerces supports XInclude with the XPointer Framework and the XPointer
element() scheme, but not with the xpointer() scheme.

The latest W3C document about the xpointer() schema is from 2002 but
is still just a draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-xpointer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the xerces I implemented the XPointer xpointer() scheme under a GSoc project.But that support  needs to be improved further in order to be available.I think there is no other support for this as well.Xerces might support this in future .

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you:
http://etourdot.github.io/xincproc/

xpointer functions are not supported but xpath in the xpointer scheme is fully implemented.
Samples here: http://etourdot.github.io/xincproc/xpointer/specs/org/etourdot/xincproc/xpointer/xpointer/XPointer.html